# Vue-TypeScript Application TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I am new to Vue 3 & TypeScript and using PrimeVue.  I am trying to learn by creating a simple todo app.  I run into an error that says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
at Proxy.containerClass (menu.esm.js:306:50)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1144:39)
at Object.get [as containerClass] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3427:30)
at menu.esm.js:346:33
at Proxy.renderFnWithContext (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:853:21)
at Proxy.<anonymous> (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1947:78)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:896:44)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5580:57)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
```

I'm not sure what it means.  I searched through the [code](https://github.com/isogunro/vue3ToDo) for **config** but still didn't understand what the problem is.
Here's a snippet if it's helpful.

```
 <script setup lang="ts">
 import { ref } from 'vue';
 import Menubar from 'primevue/menubar'
 import Menu from 'primevue/menu';

    const items = ref([
        {  
            items: [{
                label: 'Search',
                icon: 'pi pi-search',
                uri: './LeftNavigation.vue'
            },
            {
                label: 'View Completed',
                icon: 'pi pi-check-square', 
                uri: ''
            },
            {
                label: 'Delete',
                icon: 'pi pi-trash',
                uri: ''
            },
            {
                label: 'View Archived',
                icon: 'pi pi-cloud-upload',
                uri: ''
            },
            {
                label: 'View All',
                icon: 'pi pi-list',
                uri: ''
            },                                                                
        ]},
    ]);
   </script>

   <template>
     <div style="background-color:brown;width:50px">
       <Menu :model="items" />
     </div>
   </template>

   <style lang="scss" scoped>

   </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've [mounted the app](https://github.com/isogunro/vue3ToDo/blob/889578f/src/main.ts#L13) **before** installing the PrimeVue plugin:

```js
// main.ts
⋮
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app') 
app.use(PrimeVue)
app.use(DialogService)
```

That leads to the error you encountered when the PrimeVue component attempts to find its config, which is supposed to be setup by the plugin.

#### Solution

Mount the component as the last initialization step:

```js
// main.ts
⋮
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(PrimeVue)
app.use(DialogService)
app.mount('#app')
```